# Cannot run recent versions of Node.js in Vagrant box anymore

Tags: vagrant, node.js, sockets, npm

I like to do my dev work in Vagrant virtual machines to keep a clean environment.

Having recently updated Node.js to v18.18.0, I suddenly cannot [run `npm` commands inside the guest](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/13263) any longer:

`npm start`:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -95
npm ERR! Could not read package.json: Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, read

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2023-09-20T08_13_54_770Z-debug-0.log
```

`npm install mocha`:

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, write
```

The above is repeated infinitely.

The issue is present with any Node.js version >= 18.18 and guest OS ubuntu64/jammy as well as ubuntu64/lunar. Upgrading npm does not resolve it either. I'm at a loss for what is happening, especially since googling the message did not yield anything useful.

Is anybody else having this issue, or has an idea how to repair it?

Answer (score 0):

As observed by [some](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/13263#issuecomment-1824931590) people, the problem seems to related to the code residing on a shared directory and it's possibly related to core Nodejs ESModule loader code refusing to work in this condition. Workaround for now is moving the code to a non remote storage.